# why my page is not loading after calling redirect?

Tags: javascript, node.js

homepage function is printing log - into homepage but it is not returning my homepage.ejs

```
let anotherpage = (req, res) => {
    return res.redirect("/homepage");

// module associated with /homepage route
let homepage = (req,res) => {
    console.log("into homepage")
    return res.render("homepage.ejs")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell express to set EJS as view engine.

```js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Also you have to define GET method route like this

```js
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    console.log("into homepage");
    res.render("homepage.ejs");
});
```

Remove return from the arrow function. **res.render** will send the home page template to the browser.